# Why is it necessary to use '$' sign in AT & T assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, gnu-assembler

I am new to assembly language. I recently stepped into something miserable.
I created a sample assembly program as follows:

head.h

```
#define _Length_ 0x0A
```

main.S

```
movw $_LENGTH_, %ax
movw _LENGTH_, %ax
```

Now what is the difference between the two MOV statements?
What will be the value of ax?

I am using Ubuntu and GAS assembler(AT & T syntax).

Thanks in advance

Comment: movw $ _ LENGTH _ , %ax, moves an immediate value of 0x0a into ax, while movw _ LENGTH _, %ax probably attempts to move a 16 bit word from location 0x0a in memory into %ax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` and `%` decorators in AT&T syntax makes it simpler to parse (for the assembler, not necessarily for humans).

---

I'm going to pretend that you actually wrote `#define _LENGTH_ 0x0A` instead of `#define _Length_ 0x0A`.

If not, then `_LENGTH_` is treated as an external symbol by the assembler, and `_Length_` is a macro you defined that never gets substituted anywhere, so the assembler never knows it exists.  The C preprocessor is totally separate from the assembler, just like in C.

---

**`$` always means an immediate constant**.  So `movw $0x0A, %ax` puts 0xA into AX.

A number or symbol without a `$` as an operand always means a memory operand.  `movw 0x0A, %ax` is a load from address `[ds:0xA]` into AX (using NASM notation for an effective address).  This is almost never what you want.

---

`movw $undefined_symbol, %ax` will assemble (use `objdump -drwC` to see the relocation info in the `.o`), but fail at link time.

Comment: What about ljmp $0, _LENGTH_ ? What will this statement do? Thanks.

Comment: @PantherCoder: Apparently `ljmp` is the gas mnemonic for `far jmp`.  That fails to assemble because there is [no JMP encoding](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html) with an immediate segment but a memory-indirect offset.  `ljmp $0, $0xa` assembles (in 32-bit mode only; in 64-bit mode gas doesn't support ljmp).  But with `gcc -c -m32`, `ljmp $0, 0xa` : `gcc -m32` says `Error: operand type mismatch for 'ljmp'`.  Also, `ljmp $0, $some_symbol` assembles fine, and might actually work if the code segment you're jumping to has the same base as the current one.